# Virtual function definition in base class gives error

Tags: c++

I had written a set of classes to check composition pattern.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include "InvalidCompositeException.h"

using namespace std;
class Composite;
class Component {
public:
    Component() {}
    virtual ~Component() {}
    virtual string getName() = 0;
    virtual int getNetPrice() = 0;

    virtual Composite* getComposite() {
        try {
            throw myEx;
        } catch (InvalidCompositeException& e) {
            cout<<"Exception: "<<e.what();
        }
        return 0;
    }
    **virtual void add(Component* c);
    virtual void remove(Component* c);**
private:

};

class Composite : public Component {
public:
    Composite():mChildList(new list<Component*>()) {}
    virtual ~Composite() {
        mChildList->clear();
        delete mChildList;
    }
    virtual string getName() {return "Composite";}
    virtual int getNetPrice() {
        list<Component*>::iterator i;
        int sum = 0;
        for(i=mChildList->begin(); i!= mChildList->end(); ++i) {
            sum = sum + (*i)->getNetPrice();
        }
        return sum;
    }
    virtual void add(Component* c) {
        mChildList->push_back(c);
    }
    virtual void remove(Component* c) {
        mChildList->remove(c);
    }

private:
    list<Component*>* mChildList;
};

class Container: public Composite {
public:
    Container() {}
    virtual ~Container() {}
    string getName() {
        cout<<"container"<<endl;
        return "container";
    }
};

class Line: public Component {
public:
    Line(): mNetPrice(50) {}
    ~Line() {};
    int getNetPrice() { return mNetPrice; }
    string getName() {
        cout<<"line"<<endl;
        return "line";
    }

private:
    int mNetPrice;
};

class Text: public Component {
public:
    Text(): mNetPrice(100) {}
    ~Text() {};
    int getNetPrice() { return mNetPrice; }
    string getName() {
        cout<<"Text"<<endl;
        return "Text";
    }
private:
    int mNetPrice;
};

int main(void) {
    Container* c = new Container();
    Line* l = new Line();
    Text* t = new Text();
    c->add(l);
    c->add(l);
    c->add(t);
    cout<<"total price for c is "<<c->getNetPrice();
    l->getComposite();
    delete t;
    delete l;
    delete c;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My code runs fine except when I add those bold lines in my parent class that i receive errors

```
undefined reference to `vtable for Component'   // on this line virtual ~Component() {}
undefined reference to `Component::add(Component*)'
undefined reference to `Component::remove(Component*)'
```

I have not define virtual functions to be pure. Then why do I receive those errors even if i don't define them in Line and Text Classes. If I dont add those bold declarations my code works fine. And secondly why error on destructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-pure virtual functions need to have a definition, even if they are never called (so that the linker has something to put in the vtable). Simply add `=0` to make your class abstract, or provide empty definitions.

The error with the destructor is a little more involved, but basically the compiler needs to decide in which object file to place the `vtable` for your polymophic class -- it usually does this wherever the first non-pure, non-inline virtual function is defined (with more complicated rules where there are no such functions). In this case, you're declaring two out-of-line virtual functions, but never defining them, so the compiler never writes the vtable into an object file.

Answer (score 2):

If there's no implementation in the base class, you need to make them abstract with the `=0` in the virtual function declaration. Otherwise, the virtual function table for the base class will try to find bodies - without the =0, it figures they must exist, and that will end up pointing at nothing, causing the linker error.

The destructor error is the same thing - it needs that complete table to find the virtual dtor and the table isn't complete.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
class foo
{
 public:
    void doit();
 };

foo f;
 f.doit(); // linker error, doit isn't defined!
```

What do you think happens if void doit() becomes virtual doit()? Nothing, same error as you have now. However virtual void doit() = 0 by making it pure will resolve the error. A virtual function is like any other, it must have an implementation.

Comment: Well, the point here is that if a non-virtual function is never called, you can get away with not providing a definition. Here, the base class methods are never called (both subclasses override them), but definitions are still required -- so it's actually quite different from the non-virtual case.